# Converting the value of a string to a variable of KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>

Tags: c#, typeconverter, keyvaluepair

I was doing something like this :

```
foreach( KeyValuePair<int,SOME_CLASS> reader in _readerDict )
{
  var selectedReader = reader;

  var antenna1 = selectedReader.Value.Antenna1IsEnabled;
  var antenna2 = selectedReader.Value.Antenna2IsEnabled;
  var antenna3 = selectedReader.Value.Antenna3IsEnabled;
  var antenna4 = selectedReader.Value.Antenna4IsEnabled;
}
```

But then again I want to do something like the following :

```
foreach( KeyValuePair<int,SOME_CLASS> reader in _readerDict )
{
  var selectedReader = reader;

  for( var idx = 1; idx <= 4; idx++ )
  {
    var antennaIsEnabled = string.Format( "selectedReader.Value.Antenna{0}IsEnabled", idx );

    // cast the value of antennaIsEnabled as a KeyValuePair<int,SOME_CLASS> variable datatype here
    ....
  }
}
```

Is there anyway for me to cast the value of antennaIsEnabled as a KeyValuePair variable datatype?

Comment: KeyValuePair needs 2 parts, the key and the value. Your string will be splitted then? Key = "selectedReader" and Value = "AntennaIsEnabled"

Comment: I think he has a string that contains "string strA = ..." and he wants to make this a dictionary, so the key word be "strA" and the value would be "selectedReader.Value.AnetnnaIsEnabled".

Comment: Sorry guys, I just edited the question to be more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a result that looks like this:

```
Dictionary<int, bool> AntennaIsEnabled = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
foreach( KeyValuePair<int,SOME_CLASS> reader in _readerDict )
{
  var selectedReader = reader;

  //From your example
  AntennaIsEnabled.Add(1, selectedReader.Value.Antenna1IsEnabled);
  AntennaIsEnabled.Add(2, selectedReader.Value.Antenna2IsEnabled);
  AntennaIsEnabled.Add(3, selectedReader.Value.Antenna3IsEnabled);
  AntennaIsEnabled.Add(4, selectedReader.Value.Antenna4IsEnabled);
}
```

Then you can access the state of each antenna by using a syntax like AntennaIsEnabled[2].

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to extract the `selectReader` as key and `AntennaIsEnabled` as value

```
string[] parts = strA.Split('.');
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(part[0], part[2]));
```

Need to add some error checking...

Answer (score 0):

Try using **[FastMember](http://nuget.org/packages/FastMember)** library to access your properties as strings.